Espresso test recorder will not record elements in a webview for an Ionic app with webviews
I launched the test recorder for the Ionic app.  It will record native elements and actions like setting permissions and such.  But, anything I click on inside a webview, it does not record.  I did see posts 8 years ago about the test recorder not working with webviews.  But, I am checking to see if I am missing something that Espresso updated or some new settings that allows recording for webviews?  I find it hard to believe that Google has not updated the test recorder to record things that I can find with Espresso web myself ( using the Chrome inspector to get selectors, ids, tag names, etc. and plugging them into Espresso web ).
I do the same recording in XCUITests for iOS and I am able to record just about everything under the webviews.  It would be nice to be able to do the same thing for Android.  Anyone know if this is possible now?
